# Many-to-many relationship with predefined types

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, relationship, entity-relationship, rdbms

Each process has multiples operations. Each operation has an unique duration (seconds) depending on the process it belongs, an operation may belong to multiples process.

[image]

The problem is that I have to use a list of predefined "types" and each process/operation must belong to the same "type". In other words, a process of "type A" can not have operations of "type B", the same thing goes on the other side.

I tried the following approach without success. Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- type common to process and operation 
--
po_type {type_id, type_name}
     PK {type_id}
     AK {type_name}


operation {operation_id, operation_type}
       PK {operation_id}
       SK {operation_id, operation_type}
       FK {operation_type} REFERENCES po_type {type_id}


process {process_id, process_type}
     PK {process_id}
     SK {process_id, process_type}
     FK {process_type} REFERENCES po_type {type_id} 


-- operation_process
-- process_operation_no is an integer (1,2,3 ..) for each process_id
--
op_proc {process_id, process_operation_no, operation_id, the_type, duration}
     PK {process_id, process_operation_no}
    FK1 {process_id, the_type}   REFERENCES process   {process_id, process_type}    
    FK2 {operation_id, the_type} REFERENCES operation {operation_id, operation_type}
```

---

```
Notes: PK = primary key 
       AK = alternate key (use unique constraint/index)
       SK = superkey      (use unique constraint/index)
       FK = foreign key
```

---

I have allowed here for an operation to repeat in the process, not sure if that makes sense in your model -- if not simply drop the `process_operation_no` and use `operation_id` in the PK.

---

**EDIT**

Bit nicer by keeping the `type_id` name everywhere; also without `process_operation_no` -- not allowing the operation to repeat within the process.

```
po_type {type_id, type_name}
     PK {type_id}
     AK {type_name}


operation {operation_id, type_id}
       PK {operation_id}
       SK {operation_id, type_id}
       FK {type_id} REFERENCES po_type {type_id}


process {process_id, type_id}
     PK {process_id}
     SK {process_id, type_id}
     FK {type_id} REFERENCES po_type {type_id} 


op_proc {process_id, operation_id, type_id, duration}
     PK {process_id, operation_id}
    FK1 {process_id,   type_id} REFERENCES process   {process_id,   type_id}    
    FK2 {operation_id, type_id} REFERENCES operation {operation_id, type_id}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was expecting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this looks like a classic case of ternary relationship.

Eg:

> Professor <-> Subject <-> Course

[image] Source:[Data Modeling and Database Design
 By Richard W. Scamell, Narayan S. Umanath](http://books.google.com/books?id=1zbZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=professor%20subject%20course%20ternary&source=bl&ots=ADdGE3Ll6s&sig=1bds6qDG6DUupxrin2ncwgEUljk&hl=mr&sa=X&ei=Cw7hU7GXFdKlyASL84HADw&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=professor%20subject%20course%20ternary&f=false)

Now, Process, Operation, and Type are three entities having a ternary relationship.

The logical schema will have this ternary relationship. It will decompose into multiple m:n OR 1:n relationships (depending on the domain constraints). After that, you can model them as any other m:n in the schema.

For more, you can refer to the

> Section 5.5.1 Decomposing Ternary and Higher-Order Relationships

from the same book.

Also, you can see this:

[Analysis of Binary/Ternary Cardinality Combinations
in Entity-Relationship Modeling](http://cci.drexel.edu/faculty/song/publications/p_DKE96.PDF)

Comment: This will help me to improve my theoretical knowledge. Thanks!